# Can " was" and "were" be used interchangeably?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english

I am reading Post Office by Charles Bukowski. The writing style of the book is quite conversational and colloquial. This is a paragraph from the book.

> As I stood there, the 10,000 flies began to come back down out of
> the sky, settling down in the grass, along the fence, the ground, in
> my hair, on my arms, everywhere. One of the bolder ones bit me.
> I cursed, ran out and bought the biggest fly sprayer you ever saw.
> I fought them for hours, raging we were, the flies and I, and hours
> later, coughing and sick from breathing
> the fly killer, **I looked around and there was as many flies as ever.**
> I think for each one I killed they got down in the grass and bred two.
> I gave it up.

Shouldn't it be,"I looked around and there **were** as many flies as ever."  Or, can " was" and "were" be used interchangeably?

Comment: It might be a stylistic choice, or you can see "as many flies as ever" collectively as one problem.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Will this be looked down upon in formal writing?

Comment: They are not interchangeable, but consider "There was *a crowd of* golden daffodils".

Comment: No, *were* and *was* cannot be used interchangeably. They are different words and they mean different things. If you look them up in a dictionary, you will see when to use them.